# How to access the id of the Primary class in the foreign class in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have 2 model classes(Album and Songs) where Song is d foreign class.
I want to access the id of the Album class in the Song class.
How can i do that??

```
class Album(models.Model):
   artist=models.CharField(max_length=250)
   title=models.CharField(max_length=500)

class Song(models.Model):
   album=models.ForeignKey(Album,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   song_title=models.CharField(max_length=250)

   def get_absolute_url(self):
   //I need to access the Album ID from here..so that i can 
   redirect myself to the Album's url after adding a new song
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackOverflow!  So, what I assume your code here looks like is something like:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Song(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    song_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='songs')
```

Lets say you've gotten a song record by doing `song = Song.objects.get(id=x)`. Then you would get the album id by the following:
`song.album.id`

Comment: Thank you for your response..I have edited and mentioned the exact method right above

Answer (score 0):

Above is the correct code. But, you don't need an extra field of id in both classes. That is why, Django already created this type of field in DB.

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_name
class Song(models.Model):
    song_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='songs', on_delete='CASCADE')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_name
```